# Fastest collection for collection of items which each has collections of items to iterate through

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have a small collection (about 10 items) that each has a medium collection (from 200 to sometimes 500) of items linked (Many-to-one relationship, if I'm correct).

I am looking for a way to iterate through the lists like this:

```
var cardSetQry = from cs in mDb.CARD_SET
                 select cs;

List<CARD_SET> listCardSets = cardSetQry.ToList();

Dictionary<string, List<CARD>> cardsList = new Dictionary<string, List<CARD>>();

foreach (var cardSet in listCardSets)
{
    CARD_SET set = cardSet;    
    var cardQry = from c in mDb.CARD
                  where c.CARD_SET_IDE == set.CARD_SET_IDE
                  select c;

    if (cardQry.Any())
    {
        HashSet<CARD> listCards = new HashSet<CARD>(cardQry.ToList());    
        foreach (var card in listCards)
        {
            card.CARD_MASTER_IDE = null;
            card.CARD_CHILD_IDE = null;

            mDb.SaveChanges();
        }    
        cardsList.Add(set.CARD_SET_NAME, listCards);
    }
}
```

I'm using the `dictionary` because I need both the card set name and the list of objects related, but I'm open to suggestions. This method is called once when the app is started and has to iterate through every items.

As for the second list (`HashSet`), I've started using this since last week. Small research made me believe that a hashSet is a fast collection type. But I don't know how it works.

So, the question: to achieve what I need to do, what would be the fastest collections to use, and why?

Comment: _what would be the fastest collections_ is hardly an issue with 10x500

Comment: Because of the size of the collection? At which rate would it become interesting, then?

Comment: From looking at this, the biggest performance issue is actually going to be your database call. It looks like as you iterate over the items you call the database to get the next set of results. It would be better to retrieve all Cards from the DB once, then do your filter on those results.

Answer (score 2):

It's doubtful that you'll see a significant difference in the speed of enumerating a `HashSet<T>` versus enumerating a `List<T>`, regardless of the size.

Which you use should depend on how you're going to use it. If you want the ability to quickly determine if something is in the collection, then use `HashSet`. Otherwise, use `List`. `HashSet` has its uses, but as a simple sequential list, it's overkill. It also uses 3 or 4 times as much memory as does `List`.

Also, what's the point of doing `cardQry.ToList()` when creating your `HashSet`? You can just write `new HashSet<CARD>(cardQry)`.

Comment: Ah, ok. The point was rather that I did not know how to initialize a HashSet, and resharped allowed me to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

In such a small collection speed is not an issue. You should use Dictionary if you really want to map it as key value. Otherwise just use Hashset.[Comparison of Hashset list and dictionary](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/)

Comment: Ah, ok! :) At which rate would it become an issue?

Comment: see this for a comparison. http://softscenario.blogspot.com/2009/05/performance-testing-of-dictionary-list.html